# upgrading to latest release of kubuntu, but holding a package back

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu 20.1 (groovy) on my laptop which is an asus UX303U around a year ago, and I now want to upgrade to the latest release that still offers support.

The groovy version was an old one even then, but it was the only version that would install and work on my laptop. When the software was upgraded the distro wouldn't load and I just got a black screen. I have found a workaround by holding back upgrades of the package intel-microcode.

So I've already done the commands

sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

and

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

So I'm ready to do

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
sudo do-release-upgrade

My question is, if I do this upgrade will it still hold back the intel-microcode package?

Comment: You can try to dist-upgrade from 20.10 to 21.10. It might work, it might not. We have not tested it, and we don't provide support for that particular upgrade path. Unless you apt-pin that intel-microcode package, apt will dist-upgrade it along with the rest of your system. If the upgrade fails, then the pinning is academic, since you will need to reinstall.

Comment: You are setting yourself up to do this upgrade multiple times: 20.10 to 21.04, then 21.04 to 21.10. It might work, it might not. But it will be slow. Instead, try a 21.10 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to see if your hardware works properly -- that's why the environment is there. While you are at it, test a 22.04 LiveUSB, too. If they work without you needing to muck about with microcode apt-pins and other haywiring, If they work, a reinstall might be simpler and faster.

Comment: There is no 20.1 release (no release occurred in 2020-January; 20.10 was the 2020-October release).  Ubuntu 20.10 was intended to *release-upgrade* to 21.04; but that upgrade step ended when [21.04 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/) so your QA-tested & supported upgrade paths are gone.  As I understand it you'll get an *upgrade not supported* error & failure to upgrade due to Supported:0 read from https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. You could *spoof* that but I'd just re-install a *supported* system.

Comment: FYI:  You can easily *upgrade via re-install*, eg. I'm involved with the Lubuntu team, and when 21.04 reached EOL & I no longer needed that install for *support* purposes; I used it as a *jammy* QA-test install using the procedure I'm referring to, and it became a 22.04 install; with my additional packages automatically re-installed & none of my files touched; so I could continue playing music on my playlists on my non-Lubuntu music player.  The Lubuntu *testcase* is documented [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743) but it works on Kubuntu too